# How to create a Splash Screen to fit all screen sizes in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm able to display the splash screen with no problem, but I need to provide the correctly sized splash image depending on the screen resolution. In all the examples I've checked, they say to put splashscreen.png into a drawable folder and reference it it in splash.xml which is in turn referenced in a style.xml which is used as the splash activity theme.

splash.xml inside Resources > drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/launcher_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Inside Resources > values > styles.xml:

```
<style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
```

Here is my problem:

There is a drawable folder inside Resources, And there are separate mipmap folders inside Resources which are supposed to home the different sizes for splash screens. The examples I've seen only reference a single image from drawable. So the question is, how do I appropriately reference the correct splashscreen.png depending on the device resolution?

Sources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

https://www.xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/

Comment: The device itself grabs it from the correct folder, you will need to provide the appropriate image asset for each folder. In other words you will need multiples of the same image which have the appropriate resolution for mdpi, xdpi,xxdpi, etc.

Comment: Yes but how??...I have to reference the splash.png in splash.xml. that is pointing only to a single png file in drawable.

Comment: So you will need to make the same file in different resolutions, usually a designer does that, but as far as referencing it, it is still the same name. So you will have spalsh.png , for example, in your drawable, and in all the other layout folders. The platform itself will know where to look

Comment: Are you saying that I should put the splash.xml file inside the drawable folder, and then all the splashscreen.png files inside their respective folder sizes?

Comment: the xml file can stay where it is, you just need to put the splashscreen.png in its respective folder size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image needs to be referenced only from drawable folder and other folders should have the images with exact same name. Based on the resolution device automatically picks the correct drawable folder and image inside it.
For more details [Click here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp)

Comment: I need to clarify something. You say the image needs to be in drawable. Which version of the image? the highest res version?

Comment: lowest, since it follows hierarchy high to low. If you have folders like hdpi, mdpi, ldpi and default drawable and if device is hdpi it will search for image in hdpi first then if it is not available it will go for mdpi then ldpi then for default drawble.